# How to use bookmark for jumping to another file with PDFLib?

Tags: pdflib

I want to create a link or a bookmark in pdf that take me to the another pdf with PDFLib. For that I have used following code:

```
String optlist = "filename=paper_planes_catalog.pdf " +"destination={page 2 type fixed left 50 top 200 zoom 2}";
```

Now I have created the action for that as follow:

```
goto_action = p.create_action("GoToR", optlist);
```

But how can I apply that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the bookmark for that.

```
String optlist = "action={activate " + goto_action + "} fontstyle=bold textcolor={rgb 0 0 1}";

catalog_bookmark = p.create_bookmark("Our Paper Planes Catalog", optlist);
```

That will do the remaining.